# Does anyone offer shidduch resume writing classes?

Tags: shidduchim-dating

Follow up to this [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40127/5275).

In my neighborhood, the handful of shadchanim / ot are busy organizing and managing the shidduchim, themselves. My kids and I could use some hands-on assistance in writing a shidduch resume as well as, perhaps, some practical advice to the shidduch process and behavior. (I thought that when I dated I had "good" behavior, but, a few have told me that these days, boys cannot do many of the things that I did (halachic reasons, they explain.))

I live in the New York area. Are there any individual advisors, group classes or events where they offer practical hands-on advice? The online guide is useful, but it doesn't address some of my questions or some unusual situations that I have with one of my children. (For privacy, I don't want to delve much into what it is.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

- Ask a few older friends to send copies of their resumes. Use them as a template for your children
- Ask a Rav/Rebbetzin/Wise friend to give you an hour or so of coaching
- Find a know-it-all in your community who will be happy to answer any and all of your questions to the best of their knowledge. Just be careful not to take them to seriously :)
- Find a Frum social skills therapist or dating coach

Please remember that dating is an individual matter. As much as people might strongly express their opinions of "this is the only way it's done", remember that everyone finds their own way in dating and marriage. Even in the more Yeshivish world.